# Is it possible to output html instead of a string as the object value when using nuxt-i18n?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

Is it possible to output html instead of a string as the object value when using nuxt-i18n?

It would be great if you could teach me!

**en.json**

```
{
  "HELLO_WORLD": "<p>Hello World<p>"
}
```

**pages/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    { $t('HELLO_WORLD') }}
  </div>
</template>
```

■Desired result

```
<div>
  <p>Hello World<p> ←　html tag
</div>
```

■Actual results

```
<div>
　　<p>Hello World<p> ←　Tags are also strings
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML ??

Answer (score 1):

simply replace your template by using below code:

```
<template>
  <div v-html="$t('HELLO_WORLD')">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll try later

What if I don't want to write a wrapped div?
For example, react.fragment

Comment: you can use <span v-html="rawHtml"></span>

Comment: In this case, it will be wrapped in <span>. Is this a specification?
Is there a way to write if you don't want to be wrapped in any tags?

Comment: in that case just modify en.json like: {
  "HELLO_WORLD": "Hello World"
}
and use this like:
<p v-html="$t('HELLO_WORLD')">
  </p>

Comment: Certainly in this case, wrapping the <p> tag will solve it, thank you.

But is it possible to output only the html described in the json inside without generating any tags?

For example, in an html file with nothing written